# SpringData ElasticSearch insert/update multiple documents

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

My goal is to do insert and update multiple documents in ElasticSearch using `ElasticsearchRepository`.

```java
public interface EmployeeInfoRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<EmployeeInfo, String> {

}
```

However, whenever I call `saveAll(entities)`, the number of document is unchanged but it creates new indexes for those entities.

```java
employeeInfoRepository.saveAll(employeeInfos);
```

If I insert 1000 elements, at first it will have 1000 docs and 1000 indexes, which is what I expected. Then I call `saveAll` two more times, it still has 1000 docs but now the number of indexes increases to 3000.

How can I update it properly?

[image]

It would be the best if it's just as easy as calling `saveAll` and the rest is handled by SpringBootData ElasticSearch.

**Update 1:**

- There is no change with the data, however when I run `saveAll`, the `storage_size` keeps increasing. Not sure if it creates the indexes again and still keeps the old indexes.

Comment: I will suggest to update your question and not post another question or part of question as answer. below your question there is `edit` button so you can click on that and update question.

Comment: Did my answer help you? or do you want me to add something to my answer? otherwise, feel free to accept my answer if you like.

Answer (score 0):

If you define the id in your document class, elasticsearch updates/inserts the document with the same document id value.
Here an example:

```java
@Document(indexName = "example_index")
public class Example  {

    @Id
    @Field(type = FieldType.Long)
    private long id;

}
```

Of course, you have to handle the logic for a unique id in your project.